# Expectation of a fraction form

Tags: expected-value

Given $X \sim  \exp(\theta)$ and $\bar{X}=\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}$, how do I find $$\Bbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{\bar{X}-2}\right]?$$

Am I allowed to do this? $$\Bbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{\bar{X}-2}\right]=\frac{1}{\Bbb{E}[\bar{X}]-2}.$$

Comment: what is $\bar{X}$?

Comment: No this would be the same as assuming $\int \frac{1}{x-2}d\mu = \frac{1}{\int x d\mu -2}$.

Comment: Also you could just try it with some numbers and even something as simple as a Bernoulli distribution fails to satisfy the given equality

Comment: @caverac edited the question.

Comment: Do you mean that every $x_i$  is a realization of $X$? Then note that $\bar{X}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ with $X_i \overset{iid}{\sim} exp(\theta)$ is gamma distributed, so i.e. you can use it's density function to calculate the given expected value.

Answer (score 1):

We'll look at a simple example.  Assume that $\theta = 1$ and $n = 2$.  As one of the comments above states, if our two observations from the exponential distribution are independent, then their sum, $X$, has a gamma distribution with parameters $2$ and $1$.  Now, if we try to write out the integral for the desired expectation --

$$ E\left[\frac{1}{X - 2}\right] = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x - 2} \cdot x e^{-x} \; dx $$

-- we have to note the singularity at $x = 2$.  That is, we have to write

$$ E\left[\frac{1}{X - 2}\right] = \int_0^2 \frac{1}{x - 2} \cdot x e^{-x} \; dx + \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x - 2} \cdot x e^{-x} \; dx. $$

Neither of these integrals converges.  For example, since $ e^{-x} > e^{-3} $ for $x < 3$, we have

$$ \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x - 2} \cdot x e^{-x} \; dx > \int_2^3\frac{1}{x - 2} \cdot x e^{-x} \; dx > e^{-3} \int_2^3 \frac{x}{x-2} \; dx, $$

an integral that diverges to infinity.

This will be true regardless of $n$ or $\theta$.

With regard to your question about whether we can rewrite the desired expectation:  $E\left[ \cdot \right]$ is a *linear* operator.  That means, for random variables $X$ and $Y$ and constants $a, b$ and $c$,

$$ E[aX + bY + c] = aE[X] + bE[Y] + c. $$

We can break sums and differences into multiple expectations, and we can pull out constants, but that's about it.  We can't pull out exponents, for example -- or else all variances would be zero -- and so, while $E[X - 2] = E[X] - 2$, we can't do anything if the $X - 2$ is stuck inside a negative exponent.